# How to get badges "Curious", "Inquisitive" and "Socratic" with non-well received questions in the past?

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

I am well aware that on my Physics Stack Exchange account, I have asked a few good questions and also some bad ones in the past.  For the Curious badge, I have an 8/5, but am unable to get it as I do not have a positive question record.  I am unable to delete those questions as others have already spent time investing an answer.  Hence, I would like to ask, given these circumstances, is there NO way that I can even get these badges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One non-well received question in the past <s>does not a summer make</s> does not disqualify you for these badges forever. In fact, most people (including me) have those. They just have the consequence that you need to make some *additional* well received questions, beyond the usual 5 for Curious.

Note that even if you would be able to delete a closed/downvoted question, it will still count as a non-well received question; in fact, it carries a **higher penalty** than just a closed/downvoted question:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative *and* Closed *and* Deleted count three times in this calculation!

(from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for))

Comment: TotalQuestions here refers to the sum of all scores from question asked right?

Comment: No, not the sum of the scores, just the 'count'. In your case on Physics 21 (+ any deleted ones you may have).

Comment: Ah @Glorfindel I understand now.  I had quite a few deleted questions in the past.